# Google Earth Engine Error: When computing PCA of Sentinel -2 Mosaiced Image

Tags: google-earth-engine, mosaic, sentinel-2, pca

I want to select an area using Rectangle or Polygon tool, mosaic Sentinel- 2 images in the selected area using the `median()` or `mosaic()` method and calculate PCA of the area. When I use a single image the process is much faster. but with `mosaic()` method it is very slow or gives me `Computational Timeout` error. Similarly, trying `median()` method gave me `User memory limit exceeded` error. I have applied PCA on larger areas without mosaicing it worked without any problems.
Can any expert guide me on how can I use `median()` and `mosaic()` methods to combine images and then apply PCA?

```js
// **** Pricipal Component Analysis and Decorrelation Stretching *****
// Select and Filter Sentinel 2 L2A Image
var sentImages = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2')
.filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', 10))
.filterDate("2000-01-02", "2020-12-30")
.filterBounds(sentclip);

var sentmosaic = sentImages.mosaic();
var sentImage = sentmosaic.clip(sentclip);

print("Sentinel 2 Scene", sentImage);

// PCA Code
var getPrincipalComponents = function(centered, scale, region) {
  // Collapse the bands of the image into a 1D array per pixel.
  var arrays = centered.toArray();
  print('PCA applying on', centered);
  // Compute the covariance of the bands within the region.
  var covar = arrays.reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.centeredCovariance(),
    geometry: region,
    scale: scale,
    maxPixels: 1e9
  });

  // Get the 'array' covariance result and cast to an array.
  // This represents the band-to-band covariance within the region.
  var covarArray = ee.Array(covar.get('array'));

  // Perform an eigen analysis and slice apart the values and vectors.
  var eigens = covarArray.eigen();

  // This is a P-length vector of Eigenvalues.
  var eigenValues = eigens.slice(1, 0, 1);
  // This is a PxP matrix with eigenvectors in rows.
  var eigenVectors = eigens.slice(1, 1);
  
  // Convert the array image to 2D arrays for matrix computations.
  var arrayImage = arrays.toArray(1);
  
  // Left multiply the image array by the matrix of eigenvectors.
  var principalComponents = ee.Image(eigenVectors).matrixMultiply(arrayImage);

  // Turn the square roots of the Eigenvalues into a P-band image.
  var sdImage = ee.Image(eigenValues.sqrt())
    .arrayProject([0]).arrayFlatten([getNewBandNames('sd')]);

  // Turn the PCs into a P-band image, normalized by SD.
  return principalComponents
    // Throw out an an unneeded dimension, [[]] -> [].
    .arrayProject([0])
    // Make the one band array image a multi-band image, [] -> image.
    .arrayFlatten([getNewBandNames('pc')])
    // Normalize the PCs by their SDs.
    .divide(sdImage);
};

// Sentinel-2 True Color Map
var trueColor = {
  bands: ["B4", "B3", "B2"],
  min: 0,
  max: 3000,
  gamma:1.5
};   
Map.addLayer(sentImage, trueColor, "Sentinel 2 True Color");

// Sentinel-2 False Color Map
var falseColor = {
  bands: ["B11", "B12", "B8"],
  min: 0,
  max: 3000,
  gamma:1.5
};
Map.addLayer(sentImage, falseColor, "Sentinel 2 False Color");

// Sentinel - 2 PCA              
// Display the input imagery and the region in which to do the PCA.
var sentbands = ['B2','B3','B4','B8','B11','B12'];
var region = sentImage.geometry();
var image =  sentImage.select(sentbands);

// Set some information about the input to be used later.
var scale = 30;
var bandNames = image.bandNames();

// Mean center the data to enable a faster covariance reducer
// and an SD stretch of the principal components.
var meanDict = image.reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
    geometry: region,
    scale: scale,
    maxPixels: 1e9
});
var means = ee.Image.constant(meanDict.values(bandNames));
var centered = image.subtract(means);

// This helper function returns a list of new band names.
var getNewBandNames = function(prefix) {
  var seq = ee.List.sequence(1, bandNames.length());
  return seq.map(function(b) {
    return ee.String(prefix).cat(ee.Number(b).int());
  });
};

var pcImage = getPrincipalComponents(centered, scale, region);

// Plot each PC as a new layer
Map.addLayer(pcImage, {bands: ['pc4', 'pc5', 'pc3'], min: -2, max: 2}, 'Sentinel 2 - PCA');

Map.setCenter(72.2653928137903,34.25603836981476, 13);
```

Comment: The script seems to work. Maybe increasing ```maxPixels``` helps.

Answer (score 1):

```
//Select and Filter Sentinel 2 L2A Image
var sentImages = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2')
.filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', 10))
.filterDate("2000-01-02", "2020-12-30")
.filterBounds(sentclip);

var sentmosaic = sentImages.mosaic();
var sentImage = sentmosaic.clip(sentclip);

print("Sentinel 2 Scene", sentImage);
```

Take this part in a separate file. Export this data as a GeoTIFF file.
Import this file in PCA code. It works.